# Assign a class for Jtabbed pane

Tags: java

I created a frame and after that a Jtabbed pane placed in
after that 3 Jpannel added,like the one below .

```
JPanel admpnl = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("ADMIN AREA", null, admpnl, null);
```

my class with the name of Admin has been created ,I wanna try to add `admpnl` which is a kind of Jpanel to a class ,i already extends from Jpanel,but I dunno how to add "admpnl" to this class.

```
public class Admin extends JPanel {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code for the `JPanel admpnl....null);` located? Is it in the Admin class or part of another class?

The quiestion might make more sense if we see more of your code, but in the meantime, you cannot add admpnl to an Admin object because Admin is already a JPanel.

Instead, you may try to take all the code after `JPanel admpnl = new JPanel();` and add it to the constructor for the Admin class so that all those JTabbedPanes get added to your Admin object when it gets created.